# Timeout while waiting for a batch of Futures to complete?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, java.util.concurrent

I have a set of `Futures` created by submitting `Callable`s to an `Executor`. Pseudo code:

```
for all tasks
  futures.add(executor.submit(new callable(task)))
```

Now I'd like to get all futures waiting at most n seconds until all complete. I know I can call `Future#get(timeout)` but if I call that sequentially for all my futures in a loop the timouts start adding up. Pseudo code:

```
for all futures
  future.get(timeout)
```

`get` blocks with a timeout until the result is ready. Therefore, if the first completes just before timeout and the second also completes just before timeout and so on the entire execution time is `number of futures * timeout` at most instead of `timeout`.

Hence, I'm looking for a method that accepts a list of `Future`s and a timeout, runs all in parallel and then returns a collection of future results. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not completely clear.  What do you want to have happen to the tasks that have not completed when the timeout expires?  Do you want them to be cancelled or allowed to continue?

Comment: They should be cancelled. Also, somehow I need to know which ones completed and which didn't. I guess for that I could iterate once more over the futures and invoke `isDone` on all of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`ExecutorService.invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first. `Future.isDone()` is true for each element of the returned list. Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

---

If you already have `Future`s that you need to monitor and can't use `invokeAll`, you can simply measure the timeout yourself. Pseudo code:

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMS;
for(f : futures)
    f.get(Math.max(0, endTime - System.currentTimeMillis()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This way you give each future at most the duration that is left until you reach your timeout.

Comment: `ExecutorService.invokeAll` sounds like what I'm after, thanks. For all futures that weren't completed in time `isCancelled==true`, right (that's how I interpret Javadoc)? How would I find out if a `Future` completed with exception? "Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception" - that's difficult...

Comment: @MarcelStör Yes, futures that weren't completed are canceled (`isCancelled() == true`). You then determine what happened to a `Future` when you call it's [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) (after `invokeAll` returns). If `get` throws `CancellationException`, you know it has been cancelled. If it throws `ExecutionException`, it means the the `Future` completed with an exception, and the exception is accessible through `ExecutionException.getCause()`.