# How to call a method in parallel which returns the future?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice, callable

I have an async method as shown below which calls my Task class and my Task class does all the work.

```
    @Override
    public Future<DataResponse> executeAsync(DataKey key) {
        Future<DataResponse> future = null;

        try {
            Task task = new Task(key, restTemplate);
            future = executor.submit(task); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // logging exception here
        }

        return future;
    }
```

Below is my `Task` class which does all the work:

```
public class Task implements Callable<DataResponse> {

    private DataKey key;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(DataKey key, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse call() throws Exception {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Now I need to call `executeAsync` method in parallel and then make a `List<DataResponse>` object and return it.

```
@Override
public List<DataResponse> executeSync(DataKey key) {
    List<DataResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<DataResponse>();

    // make a List of DataKey using single key passed to this method.       
    List<DataKey> keys = new ArrayList<DataKey>();

    for(DataKey key : keys) {


    }
}
```

How can I call `executeAsync` method in parallel and return back `responseList`? In my `keys` list maximum I will have six `DataKey` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting to return a `List<DataResponse>` containing the `DataResponse` objects returned by `Task#call`, you can't do this asynchronously. You'll need to block inside `executeSync` to wait for the result of all futures.

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>(keys.size());
for(DataKey key : keys) {
    Future<DataResponse> future = executeAsync(key);
    futures.add(future);
}

for (Future<DataResponse> future : futures) {
    try {
        responseList.add(future.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something else.
    }
    return responseList
}
```

A more appropriate solution with `Future` is to use a `CompletionService`, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future).

In Java 8, you should be using [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (or Guava's `ListenableFuture`) for asynchronous tasks. You can still do what I did above, or you can change your code to take full advantage of continuation tasks.

Comment: So in this example, let's say I have 3 futures and then we are iterating them in for loop, in the try block it will call future.get for first future and then it will wait once that is finished, it will call second second future right?

Comment: Is there any way to call all futures get method at once? I am still on Java 7.

Comment: That's right. `get` is a blocking call. `CompletionService` makes this a little better. _call them all at once_ would be akki's solution but you have to change around some things in your code and it actually does the same thing internally.

Comment: just trying to under when you say same thing internally what does that mean? So it looks like there is no way to call all futures get method in paralell?

Comment: @david Look at the source code of [`invokeAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java#AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). You can call them in parallel but that's probably more trouble than it's worth. You'll always have to block somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Executor service invokeAll method and submit List of Task to it. Executor Service will execute the tasks in parallel.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)

This would be same as: 
1. invoking executeAsync in parallel from the for loop in executeSync method. 
2. invoking executeAsync method sequentially from the for loop in executeSync method.

Comment: so that means all my futures get method will be called in parallel? Can you provide an example for that if possible?

Comment: @david No, they won't be called in parallel. The calls are just hidden from you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to execute it in parallel as internally it already runs in parallel. The only thing you need is calling the async method for each of the items and store resulting `Future`s in the list. After this loop is over you need to go through the list of those `Future`s, and calling `get()`on each of them gives the result. These result list you'll return as the return value.

Comment: So when we call get on each of the future, that will be sequential call right? I mean call get on first future, then second future and then third future one by one. Is there any way to call all futures get method at once?

Comment: It cannot be anything other than sequential as you're appending the result into list which is data structure that must be accessed sequentially. But this operation is very quick as it just checks whether the future is already finished and returns immediately. The execution typically already finished once you call the get.

Comment: So wait, you mean to say once I add all the futures into the list and before I call get on first future it might have already been finished? If it is true, can you explain that if possible? Still learning so it will help me.

Comment: Yes. The task you submit to ExecutorService runs in different thread and is started immediately (or once some of the ExecutorService threads becomes available).

Comment: I see, so the suggestion given by `SotiriosDelimanolis` will work and it is doing the same thing as you are suggesting right?