# Waiting on futures

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that has bunch of threads(around 5) making calls to a Network resource. I have a future for all threads and if one of thread returns the result I am fine. Is there an efficient way of doing this in java. Right now I am doing

```
for(future : futureList) {   
   future.get().    // This is blocking. 
}
```

I am looking for a way of getting the results of each future as soon as its done.

Comment: Why not use the observer pattern to do that?

Comment: If you have an action you want to perform when the task has completed, I would add this to the end of the task and it can happen asynchronous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future This might help

Answer (score 0):

Look at [CompletableFuture.thanAccept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-)