# how to measure scala thread pool time?

Tags: multithreading, scala, threadpool

Hi I wonder how to measure thread pool time in scala.

Here is a example.

```
val pool = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)

val start_time = System.nanoTime()
1 to 10 foreach { x =>
  pool.execute(
    new Runnable {
      def run {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            println("n: %s, thread: %s".format(x, Thread.currentThread.getId))
        }finally{
            pool.shutdown()
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
val end_time = System.nanoTime()

println("time is "+(end_time - start_time)/(1e6 * 60 * 60))
```

But I think this is not working properly.

Is there any methods to measure the time?

Comment: What is "thread pool time"?

Comment: The thread pool time means total running time.
If I use end_time and start_time in this code, the result of time is not working properly.

Comment: So why you're calling it thread pool time but not total running time?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous threads in your snippet.

- main thread where you've created fixed thread pool and execute the loop.
- 10 threads that are "sleeping" 2 seconds and printing some stuff.

Your main thread as soon as it create 10 threads *finish its work and print time*. It does not wait for all parallel threads to be completed.
What you have to do is await results from all threads and only then perform total time calculation.

I would suggest you to learn a bit about concept of `Future` which will allow you to wait for result properly.

So your code might looks like following:

```
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

val start_time = System.nanoTime()
val zz = 1 to 10 map { x =>
  Future {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("n: %s, thread: %s".format(x, Thread.currentThread.getId))
  }
}
Await.result(Future.sequence(zz), Duration.Inf)

val end_time = System.nanoTime()

println("time is " + (end_time - start_time) / (1e6 * 60 * 60))
```

I've used default global scala thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Could you answer one more question? If you don't mind?
When I use your code in spark-shell, I got error like this.
`error: object java.util.concurrent.Future is not a value
         Future {
` and `error: not found: value Duration
       Await.result(Future.sequence(zz), Duration.Inf)` 
what is the Future value?

Comment: Do I import `import scala.concurrent.Future`??

Comment: added imports to the sample. should work fine in any scala console.

Comment: Thanks! It's worked!
This is really my last question, Is it impossible to measure running time using thread pool?

Comment: I assume by "using thread pool" you mean thread pool created by Java API instead of Scala API. Yes it's possible - learn how to use `Future` in Java and use the same concept to wait for results but all in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future

Comment: I appreciate your advice!
I'll try it!