# Join a group of threads with overall timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

Is there a way to join a group of threads simultaneously *with an overall timeout*?

Suppose we have `Collection<Thread> threads;` and `int timeout;`. If I didn't care about the timeout, I would do

```java
for (Thread t : threads)
    t.join();
```

but I want to wait until either *all* threads are done, *or a certain amount of time passes*, whichever comes first. I was searching for a (hypothetical) `ThreadGroup.join(int)` which would do this.

---

Note that what I'm asking for is different from doing

```java
for (Thread t : threads)
    t.join(timeout);
```

Rather, I'm looking for something less verbose (and perhaps more reliable) than

```java
int timeout = 10000;
for (Thread t : threads) {
    if (timeout <= 0) break;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    t.join(timeout);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // substract time elapsed from next timeout:
    timeout -= (int) (end - start);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use the `Thread` object directly? If not, you can use an `ExecutorService` and use `invokeAll()` which takes a timeout.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261808/5339661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a single CountDownLatch having a count for every thread in the group.

A controlling thread can `await(timeout, TimeUnit)` on the latch.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Start the threads that are in the group.

Each of the threads in the group should decrement the latch when it completes.

The controlling thread will wait until everything in the group has completed or the timeout happens, and because `await` returns a boolean, the controlling thread can tell whether the latch was decremented naturally or whether a timeout occurred.