# Wait for List of ListenAbleFuture returned by Kafka Send API

Tags: java, future, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have the List of ListenAbleFuture.I want to wait of this List of
 `ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>>` for atmost 15 minutes if they have not comepleted.
How can i achieve it.

Currently i am doing this but this wait for 15 min for every ListenAbleFuture which is what i dont want.

```
 for (ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> m : myFutureList) {

                    m.get(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES) ;
    }

ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> is from import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
```

I have gone through [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future) but this solution is for completablefuture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CountDownLatch`, e.g. `new CountDownLatch(50)`, add a listener to each listenable future and count the latch down in each one. You can use the same listener for all the futures rather than creating a new one each time.

Then, after sending 50 records, use `latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. If it times out you can then iterate over your futures to figure out which one(s) are not complete.

**EDIT**

```java
@Component
class Sender {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);

    public void sendThem(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, List<String> toSend) throws InterruptedException {
        List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(toSend.size());
        ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>> callback =
                new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                LOG.info(result.getRecordMetadata().toString());
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                ProducerRecord<?, ?> producerRecord = ((KafkaProducerException) ex).getProducerRecord();
                LOG.error("Failed; " + producerRecord, ex);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };
        toSend.forEach(str -> {
             ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = template.send("so61490633", str);
             future.addCallback(callback);
        });
        if (latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            LOG.info("All sent ok");
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < toSend.size(); i++) {
                if (!futures.get(i).isDone()) {
                    LOG.error("No send result for " + toSend.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks .I am trying to understand the code as i am not that good in async programming.

Comment: in your code i needed to access which messages were not sent to kafka in onFailure() method .I added a listener to each record in the loop .And my issue is solved.Just asking should i be doing that or there is any better way. https://pastebin.com/0GBNES2P

Comment: But if i change my code as given in the pastebin link Countdownlatch doesnt work as expected.It just waits for a single  future.How can i fix that in my code

Comment: The failed send value is available in the `Throwable` - cast it to `KafkaProducerException` - I updated my answer. Your `Person` is in `producerRecord.value()`.