# Get Objects value in Onfailure() method call of Kafka Send() method

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to get those Person objects which were not sent to Kafka i.e onFailure() method.

1)I created  temp array of person type and passed it to the onFailure() .But this doesnt work.It always shows the same temp[0] doest work.It always print the last value in the List.
2)I tried to create local Person object to solve the issue .But i got compilation error

"Local variable pp defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

How can i resolve this issue ?

```
class Sender {

        @Autowired
        private KafkaTemplate<String, Person> template;

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);



        Person temp= null;

        // @Transactional("ktm")
        public void sendThem(List<Person> toSend) throws InterruptedException {
            List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Person>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();


            ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Person>> callback = new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Person>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Person> result) {
                    //LOG.info(" message success 1: " + result.getProducerRecord().value());
                    LOG.info(" message success 2: " + temp);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                    LOG.info(" message failed : "  + temp);

                }
            };

            for (Person p : toSend) {

                temp=p;
                ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Person>> future = template.send("t_101", temp);


                future.addCallback(callback);
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failed send value is available in the `Throwable` - cast it to `KafkaProducerException`. Your `Person` is in `producerRecord.value()`.

I updated my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490633/wait-for-list-of-listenablefuture-returned-by-kafka-send-api/61491284#comment108891114_61491284).

You can also create a new callback in the loop and then `p` will be available to you; but it's more efficient to use a single callback and get the `Person` from the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But how did you find we need to cast it to KafkaProducerException .I tried to find in the link but could't get any answer.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#spring-integration

Comment: Because I wrote the `KafkaTemplate` :) After posting this, I realized that it's not explained in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#sending-messages). So I have added it now: `The Throwable in onFailure can be cast to a KafkaProducerException; its producerRecord property contains the failed record.`

Comment: Yes I noticed you have written.Thanks .It will be useful for others going forward.

Comment: I will make some improvements in the next release. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1475