# Multiple Socket Servers in single netty server

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, server, netty

I am trying to develop a socket server supporting TCP sockets and WebSockets. I created two ServerBootsraps with their channels and handlers. I started them with different ports with (skipping unnecessary code parts because they are working ok)

```
...
ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(port);
...
...
ChannelFuture channelFutureWebsocket = serverBootstrapWebSocket.bind(webSocketPort);
```

In the tutorials I've seen, they were all ending with `serverBootstrap.bind(port).sync();` But If I end with sync, the server stops and waits for packets and I cannot start the other server (as expected). If I don't end with sync, the server runs ok but I am doubtful if it will cause an error in the future.

If my method, skipping `sync()`, is wrong, how can I run 2 different servers simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc on the `Future.sync` says: *"Waits for this future until it is done, and rethrows the cause of the failure if this future failed."*

So what you want to do is get both futures and wait on them both instead of waiting on the 1st future before you've even had a chance to bind the 2nd server.

A simple way to wait on 2 futures is to use a while loop and check both futures using non-blocking methods

```java
ChannelFuture bindFuture1 = bootstrap1.bind(port);
ChannelFuture bindFuture2 = bootstrap2.bind(port);

while (!bindFuture1.isDone() && !bindFuture2.isDone()) Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL);

//Evaluate both futures to see if there were any errors, wait for the other future to be done or do whatever else you need to based on your requirements.
```

I suggest you read up on futures to understand what the `sync` method does and why it's necessary. Also have a look here: [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future)