# CompletableFuture<Boolean> as return type does not work as expected

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method in Java which should return a CompletableFuture<Boolean<> and I have some issues with the case when it is supposed to be true. My Method is below:

```
@Override
    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(String name, Object data, Object message) {

        switch (name) {
            case ("first"):

                Map<String, Long> finalAmount = (Map<String, Long>) data;
                finalAmount.forEach((id, amount) -> {
                     event.retrieveEvent(id)
                            .thenCompose(config -> {
                                update(id, amount, config);
                                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
                            });
                });
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
    }
```

The problem is that I have a map and I have to iterate over it and do something for each value. Even though it always enters the part with "CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)" - in the end, it always goes to the final "return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false)" and it returns false instead of true.

What can I do and how should I rewrite my method in order to return true after the map elements finish and for each one, everything worked and it returned true?

Comment: What is `retrieveEvent` method signature? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: yes, it also returns a CompletableFuture

Comment: The 'return' returns from the body of the innermost lambda expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future)

Comment: nope, it does not

Comment: this has nothing to do with `CompletableFuture`, but with basic understanding of java code. replace your code in `thenCompose` with an anonymous inner class... and things will probably make sense then.

Answer (score 1):

The code never stops to wait for the result of the case `case("first")`, so it will schedule a `CompletableFuture` to compute it and continue to the `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);`.

This is one possible solution:

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(String name, Object data, Object message) {
        switch (name) {
            case ("first"):
                CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture( null );
                Map<String, Long> finalAmount = (Map<String, Long>) data;
                finalAmount.forEach((id, amount) -> {
                     result = result
                         .thenCompose(v -> event.retrieveEvent(id))
                         .thenAccept(config -> update(id, amount, config));
                });
                return result.thenApply(v -> Boolean.TRUE);
             
        }         
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
```

If you want to run all the tasks in parallel, an alternative solutions is:

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(String name, Object data, Object message) {
        switch (name) {
            case ("first"):
                Map<String, Long> finalAmount = (Map<String, Long>) data;
                CompletableFuture<Void>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<>[finalAmount.size()];
                AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
                finalAmount.forEach((id, amount) -> {
                     futures[index.getAndIncrement()] = event
                         .retrieveEvent(id)
                         .thenAccept(config -> update(id, amount, config));
                });
                return CompletableFuture
                    .allOf(futures)
                    .thenApply(v -> Boolean.TRUE);
        }         
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
```

Assuming that everything is thread-safe.