# Multithreading not speeding up the process in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to run **4 threads** at the same time, to hopefully speed up a process (that can be done in parallel with no problem). For now, each thread calls the same function (that always takes roughly the same amount of time), and the threads are started (almost) at the same time. Using print statements I've checked how much time was passing between each `threadX.join()`, and **the time is exactly the same as it would be if I ran the function four times sequentially**, but in the control panel I can see that the 4 threads are indeed used (at the beginning 4 of them, then once the first is joined just 3, then two, etc).

This is my code:

```java
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Foo thread01 = new Foo();
        Foo thread02 = new Foo();
        Foo thread03 = new Foo();
        Foo thread04 = new Foo();

        System.out.println("Created all thread0x");

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(thread01);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(thread02);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(thread03);
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(thread04);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
            thread4.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double value1 = thread01.getResult();
        double value2 = thread02.getResult();
        double value3 = thread03.getResult();
        double value4 = thread04.getResult();

        System.out.println("Result1: " + value1);
        System.out.println("Result2: " + value2);
        System.out.println("Result3: " + value3);
        System.out.println("Result4: " + value4);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTime / 1000.0);
```

What am I doing wrong, or what have I not understood?

Here is the code of the test class.

```java
public class Foo implements Runnable {
    private double result;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fakeMiniMax(0);
    }

    public double fakeMiniMax(int iterationNumber) {
        int total = 0;

        if (iterationNumber > 6) {
            this.result = 100;
            return total;
        }
        else {
            this.result = -1;
            return this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) / 20 +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - 45 -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) - this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) -  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) + this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1) +  this.fakeMiniMax(iterationNumber + 1);
        }
    }

    double getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

My hardware:

- 4 cores
- 8 threads
- 16GB of RAM
- The task only uses the CPU continuously until the method returns its result.
- The code of the task is all written above

Comment: @camickr That's interesting, I thought the point of multithreading was also to improve performance of a task that can be done in parallel. Is there any other way to speed up a program that would use the CPU a lot? And, is the result I'm having normal then? Thank you.

Comment: The code seems correct to me. What do the threads do?

Comment: @BuildSlayer I added it to my question. This was a simple test class that was simulating a "MiniMax" algorithm that I'm going to replace it with (if I manage to get it to work with this simpler example). It's basically a recursive algorithm that gets called 20^6 times in total.

Comment: @camickr On the contrary, CPU-bound tasks work very well concurrently if run on hardware with multiple cores.

Comment: As a test case your `Foo` class rather fails.  Are we actually supposed to do the work to figure out how many iterations that class uses recursively?  I think a simple loop would be much more readable here.

Comment: @markspace No. It was also useful to help me understand how many "ply" deep I could have searched in a minute (6), to then see the difference with multithreading.

Comment: Were you expecting the recursion to be different?  Recursion runs on a single call stack and in a single thread of execution.  You won't go "deeper" because of multi-threading.  You'll get four times the work done (four cores, four threads) but each thread goes no deeper.

Comment: @markspace That's right, In my last comment I did not explain myself well. My goal was to see IF I was able to make it run faster, and by how much, to then change the way it is ran so that multithreading is useful. Right now I'm just running it four times instead of one, so practically it would be useless. What I was expecting was that it would have taken roughly the same amount of time as running it once, on one thread only.

Comment: OK, it's possible this is just your OS scheduling.  Now that you have changed the `Foo` class (again), its operation looks like it's too short to run for a while, so the OS just runs each short task sequentially, because it can.  Concurrency is permitted in multithreading, but not guaranteed.  Remember the OS has other functions, and the cores may be in use for that.

Comment: Another thing I see is that you're using `System.currentTimeMillis()` which is not very accurate for short time periods. `System.nanoTime()` would be much better.

Comment: @markspace Thank you very much, I will use that instead. And about changing the `Foo` class, unfortunately someone else had changed it (making it very unreadable) and I had to change it back again (currently it's the correct version). Also, the program runs for about a minute like that, because each time I'm calling the method 20 times, so it gets called around 20^6 times, so it should indeed run enough time to let the system put the 4 tasks in parallel. And it seems that they do, since in the control panel it says that Java is using 60-70% CPU (when using a single thread it stays under 20%).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

I too see strange results where running your recursive tasks concurrently takes *much more* time, not less. I have no idea why.

## Details

At a glance, you code looks correct, though I did not study the recursive calls. (Minor issue: My IDE says your `FakeMiniMax#getResult` method is never called.)

## Executors framework

But… your code is obsolete. In modern Java, we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. Instead, we use the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework added to Java 5. That framework relieves us of the chore of juggling threads and managing thread pools.

As [commented by markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449628/multithreading-not-speeding-up-the-process-in-java/67449739#comment119220579_67449628), use [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) for more accurate benchmark timing. If you really want to get serious with benchmarking, use [*Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH)*](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh). Also, use `Duration` to track elapsed time rather than doing the math (`/1_000`).

### `Callable`

You want to gather a result. So we use [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) rather than [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html).

### `Double` return object

Lets use an object [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html) as the return value from our recursive method, rather than the primitive `double`. We must do this to parameterize the type of our `Callable`.

### `Future` objects

When submitting a task to an executor service, we get back a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object. This object can be used to track the completion status. We will retrieve the result of the task from this `Future` object: a `Double` object. As we submit our multiple tasks to the executor service, we collect each `Future` object returned to us.

We can submit multiple tasks to an executor service, then wait for them to finish. The current way to do so is to first call `ExecutorService#shutdown`, followed by a call to `awaitTermination` with a time-out. When the submitted tasks are done or cancelled, flow-of-control moves beyond the `awaitTermination` call.

### Example code

Here is my revised version of your `FakeMiniMax` class.

```java
package work.basil.demo.threadmark;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class FakeMiniMax implements Callable < Double >
{
    private double result;

    // `Callable` interface
    @Override
    public Double call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " at " + Instant.now() + "." );
        return fakeMiniMax( 0 );
    }

    public double fakeMiniMax ( int iterationNumber )
    {
        int total = 0;

        if ( iterationNumber > 6 )
        {
            this.result = 100;
            return total;
        } else
        {
            this.result = - 1;
            return this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) / 20 + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - 45 - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) - this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 ) + this.fakeMiniMax( iterationNumber + 1 );
        }
    }

    double getResult ( )
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is the `App` class that acts as a test harness.

```java
package work.basil.demo.threadmark;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - The `main` method of `App` is starting to run in thread ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " at " + Instant.now() + "." );
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 4 );  // Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() or  Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 4 )

        // Populate a list of tasks to be executed on background threads.
        int countTasks = 4;
        List < FakeMiniMax > tasks = new ArrayList <>( countTasks );
        for ( int nthTask = 0 ; nthTask < countTasks ; nthTask++ )
        {
            tasks.add( new FakeMiniMax() );
        }

        // Submit list of tasks to executor service. Collect each task’s `Future` object.
        List < Future < Double > > futures = null;
        try
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
            executorService.shutdown(); // Prevents adding any more tasks.
            try { executorService.awaitTermination( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            // Review the list of `Future` objects collected for each of all the tasks.
            for ( Future < Double > future : futures )
            {
                try { System.out.println( "future.get() = " + future.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( Objects.nonNull( executorService ) && ! executorService.isShutdown() )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Prevents adding any more tasks.
            }
        }

        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start );
        System.out.println( "Our " + countTasks + " tasks took " + elapsed + "." );
        System.out.println( "INFO - The `main` method of `App` is ending its run in thread ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " at " + Instant.now() + "." );
    }
}
```

Notice that we can swap out our chosen implementation of `ExecutorService`. We can use a single-threaded executor service to run our tasks sequentially using only a single core. Or we can switch to a multi-threaded executor service backed by a fixed pool of threads. Just change that one line of code to run this test yourself in both modes.

## Test results

When I run this on a fairly busy Mac mini (*way* too many web browser windows & tabs open!) with an Intel chip containing six cores but no Hyper-Threading, 32 gigs RAM, and Java 16, I get the following results.

### Single-threaded

With a single thread, elapsed time is about 2.5 minutes.

Notice how the timestamps show each `call` method running sequentially over time. The second does not start until the first is done, and so on.

Console output:

```
INFO - The `main` method of `App` is starting to run in thread ID 1 at 2021-05-09T06:05:39.348246Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 14 at 2021-05-09T06:05:39.417155Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 14 at 2021-05-09T06:06:30.348844Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 14 at 2021-05-09T06:07:07.385369Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 14 at 2021-05-09T06:07:43.701939Z.
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
Our 4 tasks took PT2M38.344593758S.
INFO - The `main` method of `App` is ending its run in thread ID 1 at 2021-05-09T06:08:17.737893Z.
```

### Four threads

With a thread-pool of four threads, elapsed time is 7 minutes!

I have no idea why this is taking *more* time rather than the single-thread time, 7 minutes versus 2.5 minutes.

Notice how the timestamps show all four tasks starting at the same moment, within the same millisecond. Then time goes by as all four do their computational work simultaneously.

Console output:

```
INFO - The `main` method of `App` is starting to run in thread ID 1 at 2021-05-09T05:52:53.511070Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 15 at 2021-05-09T05:52:53.540791Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 14 at 2021-05-09T05:52:53.540791Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 16 at 2021-05-09T05:52:53.541806Z.
INFO - The `call` method of `FakeMiniMax` is starting to run in thread ID 17 at 2021-05-09T05:52:53.541910Z.
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
future.get() = -53874.172111640604
Our 4 tasks took PT7M6.872664491S.
INFO - The `main` method of `App` is ending its run in thread ID 1 at 2021-05-09T06:00:00.406725Z.
```

## Conclusion

In my experiments running a revised version of your CPU-intensive code, like you I get crazy results. Rather than saving time, concurrency takes *more* time.

I am left befuddled by these results. I expected using four threads with six cores would cut the time by 3/4, but instead I see the time more than double. I ran this test at least a dozen times. For the single-threaded mode, I can see one of my six cores jumps to nearly 100% utilization for the whole time. In multi-threaded mode, I clearly see all 6 cores (not 4!) jump from 10-20% utilization to about 70-90% utilization. So the threads certainly seem to be running simultaneously across cores.

I hope that some one can study this code to offer an explanation.

My only uneducated wild thought: Is there only a single [Floating-Point Unit (FPU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) on my 3 GHz Intel Core i5 chip being shared across cores and therefore acting as a bottleneck for all your recursive `double` math operations? Even if that were the case, why so much slower?

---

Tip: Notice how we include a call to `Instant.now` on every call to `System.out.println`. **Study these timestamps!** When accessing [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) across threads, the output may be interleaved in unexpected ways. Never assume the sequential lines of console happened chronologically.

Answer (score -3):

`Thread.join` is a blocking operation. There is a chance the threads are being executed in the same order you call `join`. Anyway, it's not the best option to handle threads manually in Java. There are better alternatives. In your case, I would recommend you to try `Future` and `CompletionService`. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I wrote in the question, from the control panel I can see that the program is indeed using roughly 4x the CPU power than before, so it looks like the threads are indeed running the function at the same time. But then for some reason they keep running it later, or even run it twice? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: There are hundreds of threads running in the OS. You can't be sure which one will be selected to run next time

Comment: That doesn't have to do with my question. If I run one thread only, I see that the "OpenJDK Platform binary" process uses 20% CPU. If I run four threads, I see that that same process starts to use 60-70% of my CPU.

Comment: **join()** blocks the current thread, not all the other threads. So calling **join()** for all threads is not going to slow the code down. Other threads are going to work in parallel.