# Java Concurrency: Need to make 2 webservice calls simultaneously - is this correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to make web calls to 2 different services simultaneously. At the end, I zip the 2 `Response` objects into one stream. I'm using a `Callable`, but I'm not sure I'm going about this in the correct way. It seems as though I'm still going to be blocked by the first `get()` call to the `Future`, right? Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track? This is what I have so far:

```
// submit the 2 calls to the thread pool
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
Future<Mono<Response<ProcessInstance>>> processFuture =
        executorService.submit(() -> getProcessInstances(processDefinitionKey, encryptedIacToken));
Future<Mono<Response<Task>>> taskFuture =
        executorService.submit(() -> getTaskResponses(processDefinitionKey, encryptedIacToken, 100, 0));

// get the result of the 2 calls
Optional<Tuple2<Response<ProcessInstance>, Response<Task>>> tuple;
try {
    Mono<Response<ProcessInstance>> processInstances = processFuture.get();
    Mono<Response<Task>> userTasks = taskFuture.get();
    tuple = processInstances.zipWith(userTasks).blockOptional();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("Exception while processing response", e);
    // Restore interrupted state...
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return emptyProcessResponseList;
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    log.error("Exception while processing response", e);
    return emptyProcessResponseList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given: You need to wait until both tasks are complete.

If `processFuture` ends first, you'll immediately fall through and wait until `taskFuture` ends.  If `taskFuture` ends first you'll block until `processFuture` ends, but the `taskFuture.get()` call will return instantly since that task is done.  In either case the result is the same.

You *could* use `CompletableFuture`s instead and then `CompletableFuture.allOf()` but for something this simple what you have works fine.  See also [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19348248/18157)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I knew `CompletableFuture` could be used, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will block until the `processFuture` is finished, then it will block until the `taskFuture` is finished.

The callables will be processed in parallel, so here you are saving time (assuming thread pool size >= 2).